# How do I handle subdirectory dependencies in CMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, organization

I have a project where I need to run one application on multiple boards. To do this I have two exectuables that share a `main.c`, but are compiled with a different `board.c`. The directory tree is as follows:

```
CMakeLists.txt
src/
├─ board/
│  ├─ board_a/
│  │  ├─ board.c
|  |  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ board_b/
│  │  ├─ board.c
|  |  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ app/
│  ├─ main.c
├─ lib/
│  ├─ somelib/
│  │  ├─ somelib.h
│  │  ├─ somelib.c
```

In an attempt to make the root `CMakeLists.txt` smaller and more maintainable, I've created a `CMakeLists.txt` for both boards, and would like to compile each board as an object library for the main executable in the root `CMakeLists.txt` to `add_subdirectory` on and link in.

My problem is that `board.c` (as well as `main.c`) depends on `somelib`. How can I add this dependency to the subdirectory `CMakeLists.txt`? Is there a way I can do that without hard-coding a path to `somelib`? My feeling is that I should create a `CMakeLists.txt` in `somelib`, and I feel this would be easy if I were handling the library linking from the root `CMakeLists.txt`, but my confusion is that `board` is adjacent to `lib`. I'm relatively new to CMake and am not sure how to best structure these dependencies.

Comment: ***Is there a way I can do that without hard-coding a path to somelib?*** target_include_directories() target_link_libraries() are what you need. Then just link to the target in your other project and the paths are handled for you.

Comment: I have at least a `CMakeLists.txt` for each target and others depending on the hierarchy of folders. For example `board`, `lib` and `app` in my case would have their own CMakeLists.txt and so would each executable and library.

Comment: @drescherjm if I use `target_include_directories()/target_link_libraries()` in the subdirectory `CMakeLists.txt` aren't I hardcoding a path to `somelib`?

Comment: Your someLib target needs to have `target_include_directories(somelib PUBLIC somefolder)` your target that needs to use somelib needs to have `target_link_libraries( sometarget someLib)` and by doing that you setup the include folder for somelib.

Comment: but in order to link `somelib` from `board`, wouldn't I have to `add_subdirectory` with the path to `somelib` from `board` first?

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that board.c (as well as main.c) depends on somelib. How can I add this dependency to the subdirectory CMakeLists.txt? Is there a way I can do that without hard-coding a path to somelib? My feeling is that I should create a CMakeLists.txt in somelib, and I feel this would be easy if I were handling the library linking from the root CMakeLists.txt, but my confusion is that board is adjacent to lib. I'm relatively new to CMake and am not sure how to best structure these dependencies.

This is very straightforward start by linking each `board_<X>` to `somelib`'s target.

```
# in each board_<X>/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(board_<X> OBJECT ...)
target_link_libraries(board_<X> PUBLIC proj::somelib)
```

then create the target for `somelib`:

```
# src/lib/somelib/CMakeLists.txt

add_library(somelib somelib.c)
add_library(proj::somelib ALIAS somelib)

target_include_directories(
  somelib PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>")
```

As long as the top-level CMakeLists.txt includes these subdirectories via `add_subdirectory` (multiple levels is fine), then other targets can `#include <somelib.h>` and CMake will handle linking.

Comment: what does the alias do here? is that what allows each `CMakeLists.txt` in `board_<X>` to "know" about the existance of of `somelib`? or is that a result of the `PUBLIC` keyword?

Comment: The alias prevents CMake from accidentally treating `somelib` as a linker flag. Arguments to `target_link_libraries` with `::` in them are _always_ treated as CMake targets and it throws a configure-time error if not found.

Comment: I wrote up a test environment and this works. Thanks!